# Jumping to a section in an MS Word document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I've just input a form button on my Excel sheet that the users can press to get more information on how parts of my code run. I'm planning on writing a big Word document that explains the different parts of the code in different sections. I'm looking to have a button that the user can click on in Excel for each part of the code, and that will direct them to the specific section within the Word document that I'd like to link.

So I can open a specific Word document with VBA no problems, but I'm unsure how/if I can jump to sections within the Word document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Hyperlinks instead of buttons, you can jump directly to bookmarks in your Word document, no VBA needed.

E.g. create a bookmark "Section5" in your Word document.
Then create a hyperlink in an Excel cell, with this target:

```
file://your_path\your_document.docx#Section5
```

Comment: Cheers! I'm obviously trying to be smarter than I need to be :P